# open SalesForce Lead Url from website

Tags: salesforce

I have a external website.  When the User clicks on a button from external website it should open an new window showing salesforce lead detail from Salesforce website.   How can I do it? 
I should be able to pass the LeadId as argument to the salesforce url.

Answer (score 1):

If you want generate URL to lead page (for example, like this "https://cs11.salesforce.com/00QJ000000B5Npj"), you need to know two things:

1. Salesforce Lead ID
2. Salesforce Base URL to your instance (like "https://xxxx.salesforce.com")

Both things you can get from Salesforce API. Possible your website store Leads ID, so you can add configurable parameter for Base URL, which admins should to populate, and you will be able generate Leads URL without using of Salesforce API.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info.  When I login into sales force  from web it shows url ap1.salesforce.com.  Is salesforce base url can change because I am going to hardcode it?    Also noticed the  last 3 digits of Lead  Id or ContactId  from the database is missing  When I login into contactspace and view the same contact Id or lead id like the way you said  "https://cs11.salesforce.com/00QJ000000B5Npj"

Comment: You can hardcode base URL, but usually it's a bad practice, always something can be changed and it can be the cause of potential risks. As for IDs? according Salesforce documentation 15 digit ID is case-sensitive version which is referenced in the UI, 18 digit ID is case-insensitive version which is referenced through the API.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  It's a contact or lead we are going to pull what is case sensitive version?